Insert a dynamic table of constants
I am writing a program where I have to initialize a lot of constants and be able to keep a visual order to them.
I noticed there is an Insert -> Table/Matrix and I can organize them this way.
But then I started thinking if it was possible to create a table of named variables whose values can be changed dynamically. But by that I don't mean a slider. I am thinking of a box where I can write a new value. The box should already be populated with a default value, but the user of the program can change it.
This is the only dynamic part of the program I would like to implement.
I wonder if such a thing is possible or it is overly complex and doesn't add much to the organization.
For reference here is a screenshot of the table I am currently populating:

I would like to have boxes with prepopulated default values where I now have numbers. But the boxes with the entered values should correspond to the named constants.

For a single value you can do something like this:
makeControlField[Dynamic[sym_], default_] := (
  sym = default;
  Row[{ToString[Unevaluated@sym], 
    "=", InputField[Dynamic[sym], Number, Appearance -> "Frameless"]
    }, " "]
);

makeControlField[Dynamic[k], 1.2]




This will link the shown value to the variable k.
You can then generate the control grid with some Grid code to make multiple of these. Or you can copy-paste them into your grid.
Edit
Based on the comment by Domen: if you need an editable formula for other parameters, you can do this:
Clear[makeControlField];
makeControlField[Dynamic[sym_], default_?NumericQ] := (
   sym = default;
   Row[{
     ToString[Unevaluated@sym], "=", 
     InputField[Dynamic[sym], Number, Appearance -> "Frameless"]
     },
    " "
    ]);
makeControlField[Dynamic[sym_], default_] := (
   sym = default;
   Row[{
     ToString[Unevaluated@sym], "=", 
     InputField[Dynamic[sym], Hold[Expression], 
      Appearance -> "Frameless"]
     },
    " "
    ]);




In this example, I edited the value of k and fk. As you can see, fk evaluated to a Hold object, so you still need to ReleaseHold it to use the actual value.

Since it looks like the OP also wants to have non-numeric constants, I suppose the second argument of InputField should be Expression – however, this will not leave the constants in the original symbolic form ...

If you want to update the expression that defines a given constant... That would be a bit trickier. You'd have to use a Hold[Expression] inputfield for that I think. Otherwise the constants evaluate away every time.
